# PHP What is wrong with recursive function?

Tags: php

i did function for showing today date or next workday date, if is weekend. Function works great, but with return is something wrong.

```
$today = todayDate('2014-10-18'); // Saturday

    function todayDate($date) {
        if(date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
            echo 'If - ' . $date . '<br/>';
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
            todayDate($date);
        } else {
            echo 'Else - ' . $date . '<br/>';               
        }
        return $date;
    }

    echo '<br/><br/>Today: ' . $today . '<br/><br/>';
```

This function echoes following:

```
If - 2014-10-18
If - 2014-10-19
Else - 2014-10-20
```

But echo of $today (last row in code) is

```
Today: 2014-10-19
```

So, what is wrong? Last $date in function is "2014-10-20" and this value is returning to $today, but $today shows different value. Any idea?

Comment: The function is strictly speaking recursive, but you never assign the return value of the inner call to anything.

Comment: That code is hideously inefficient. You're doing repeated roundtrips from string->timestamp->string on every single call. Why don't you just pass the timestamp around and almost all of those strtotime calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kojiro pointed out in the comment, you do not assign the return value of the inner call to `todayDate()`. To change this, replace this line

```
todayDate($date);
```

with

```
$date = todayDate($date);
```

Comment: It works :-) I tought that function goes in this way todayDate(2014-10-18) > if > date+1 = 2014-10-19 > todayDate(2014-10-19) > if > date+1 = 2014-10-20 > todayDate(2014-10-20) > else > return   --> last date value was 2014-10-20. $date = todayDate($date) goes out of my head, but important is, that it works. Thank you!

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the concept of function return values. Recursive functions can lead to complicated errors.

Comment: Oh, today I looked at this function and ... I have it :-D Thanks